# How to automatically add a name from selected id in View page from controller ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to get a name from selected id in my view page

First Model

```
public class Transaction
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int supplier_id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string supplier_name { get; set; }
}
```

---

Second Model

```
public class Supplier
{
    [Key]
    public int supplier_id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string supplier_name { get; set; }
}
```

---

View Model

```
public class EvaluateSheet
{
    public IEnumerable<Supplier> Suppliers{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
}
```

---

Controller

```
public IActionResult Sheet11()
    
    {
        var sup = _db.Supplier.ToList();
        ViewBag.Sup = new SelectList(sup, "supplier_id", "supplier_name");
        return View();
    }
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Sheet11(EvaluateSheet objc)
    {
           Transaction Model = objc.Transaction;
           Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
           transaction.Id = Model.Id;
           transaction.supplier_id = Model.supplier_id;
           transaction.supplier_name = Model.supplier_name;
           _db.Transaction.Add(Model);
           Model.supplier_name = Model.Supplier.supplier_name.Where(Model.Supplier.supplier_id == Model.supplier_id);
           _db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

---

View Page

```
@model EvaluateSheet 
<form method="post">
<select asp-for="@Model.Transaction.supplier_id" asp-items="@ViewBag.Sup" value="@ViewBag.Sup" class="form-control">
                    <option selected disabled>--choose supplier--</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Transaction</button>
```

---

I want to automatically insert supplier_name field after I selected supplier_id in my View page into the database.
I have tried this in my controller but it doesn't work

```
Model.supplier_name = Model.Supplier.supplier_name.Where(Model.Supplier.supplier_id == Model.supplier_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Define an integer type variable in `EvaluateSheet` model for `example("public int Sup_id { get; set; }")` and tag it with `DropDownListFor`.

In Controller select specific data from supplier table with the help of new define `int Sup_id` and copy this data in `Model(Transaction)`.

For example:

```
Transaction Model = new Transaction();
            Supplier supl = null;
            supl = _db.Supplier.Where(x => x.supplier_id == objc.Sup_id).FirstOrDefault();
            Model.supplier_id = supl.supplier_id;
            Model.supplier_name = supl.supplier_name;
            _db.Transaction.Add(Model);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).